# Get Value from BoundField

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a form that I'm using to create a url to forward the user to. My form, called `SearchForm` has some BooleanFields, some ModelChoiceFields, some CharFields, etc. What I'd like to do, in my view, is iterate through the (bound)fields in my form, and, if there is a value (all the fields are set to `required=False`) add to a string called `search` something like `"FieldName=Value"`. Is there a way to iterate through all the fields, and do something like:

```
for item in form:
    name=item.name
    value=item.value
```

where name would then have the id of the field, and value would have the value the user entered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each in form:
    id = each.auto_id
    value = each.value()
```

Comment: Yup. I ended up coming up with that. Also need to delete the first 3 characters in id (because the ids have `id_` in front of the defined ids.

Answer (score 1):

For your task you should try use `cleaned_data` and method `def clean()` of the form.

> ```
> class SearchForm(forms.Form):
>     # Everything as before.
>     ...
>
>     def clean(self):
>         cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
>         # get value of the field:
>         # name_field = cleaned_data.get("name_field")
>
>         if conditions:
>             cleaned_data['FieldName'] = 'value'
>         # If you will want add error messages 
>         # when conditions are broken uncomment next line
>         # raise forms.ValidationError("Errors!")
>
>         # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
>         return cleaned_data
> ```

It approach must work.